# Why business logic?

Tags: c#, sql, architecture, transactions, business-logic

Let's imagine any common operation being executed on website.

After user presses button the application should:

1. Check conditions whether the operation is allowed or not (user rights, some object's consistency, relations and other things)
2. Update DB record
3. Report

This is business-logic layer's concern as it's written in tons of books.
In fact, we firstly read data from DB then we write data to DB. And in the case when data were changed by any other user/process during our checkings we will put invalid result into the database. Seemes like the problem should be well-known but i still can't find good solution for this.

The question is: why do we need business logic layer with no opportunity to maintenance business transactions?

You probably would say TransactionScope. Well, how do you prevent read data from its changes by external processes? How it's possible to UPDLOCK from business layer? If it's possible then wouldn't it all be much more expensive than doing transactions in stored procedures?

No way to bring a part of logic to DB - only the whole. Both parts #1 and #2 must be implemented in the same transaction, moreover, read data must be locked until updation has been made.

Ideas?

Comment: Normally, you would use *optimistic locking* if the chance is small that someone else changed the data in parallel. Your `UPDLOCK` on the other hand is *pessimistic locking*. There is A LOT of documentation out there about this topic.

Comment: Chance is big. Imaginine web application where users vote for some subject. I need to votes = votes + 1 after each "Vote" button pressed. I read current votes count 100, check things and write 101 value which is already wrong as 500 other people voted during that time.

Comment: That's not going to work with UPDLOCK either. If you use UPDLOCK the 500 people would be unable to vote...

Comment: No, they'll vote a bit slower and some of them will be rejected (timeouted) but with no any data inconsistency at any moment. In the case of snapshot isolation most of them will fail.

Comment: The easiest way in that case would be a stored procedure `IncrementVote`.

Comment: "This model is primarily used in environments where there is heavy contention for data, so that the cost of protecting data with locks is less than the cost of rolling back transactions if concurrency conflicts occur." (c) Microsoft about pessimistic concurrency

Comment: I already agree with you that pessimistic locking is the better choice in your scenario. That's why I suggested a stored procedure to handle the incrementation.

Comment: Yes, you're right for this simpliest situation. Now what if my votes limit has changed since i've checked it and just before i call that SP?

Comment: I guess you need to check it before you call the SP. BTW: The SP is really simple: `UPDATE Votes_Table SET Votes = Votes + 1 Where Votes_Id = i_votes_id`

Comment: The only way to ensure that in the moment of transaction i have enough quota is to get that quota and lock it until transaction is done. In other way there is a chance of non-consistency. If it's not votes but money then it all come more critical.

Comment: -1 This is nonsense. You can't make the assumption that business rules are bad in all cases just because you have some specific cases where it works better to have the logic in the database. Having the business logic in an application makes it a lot easier than having to manage stored procedures. You get something that is more testable and easier to version control.

Comment: jgauffin, i'm not new in 3-tier model and made a number apps this way. But the task i described is very common as you almost always do some checks (which requires data to be retrieved) before any updations. In most cases you dont have high loads or mistakes are not so critical but this doesnt mean that there is no problem at all.

Comment: Business rules are NOT bad. But business layer doesnt allow control consistency well and it do operations slower than if it was inside SP.

Comment: Okay, anyway thank you all for discussing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really think you are arguing this from the wrong angle.  Firstly, in your specific example, there doesn't seem to be anything saying that the change in votes by one user invalidates the attempt of another user to affect an upvote.  So, if I opened the page, and there were 200 votes for the item, and I clicked upvote, I don't really care if 10 other people have done the same in the meantime.  So, validations can be run by the business layer, and if the result is that the vote can go through, the update can be done in an atomic way using a single SQL statement (E.g. UPDATE Votes SET VoteCount = VoteCount+1 WHERE ID=@ID), or a select with UPDLOCK and update wrapped in a transaction.  The tendency for ORMs and developers to go with the latter approach is neither here nor there, you still have the option to change the implementation if you so choose.

Now, if the requirement is that an update to the vote count actually invalidates my vote, then it's a completely different situation.  In this case, we are absolutely correct to use either optimistic or pessimistic concurrency, but these are (obviously) not applicable to a website where hundreds of people may vote at the same time, for the same item.  The issue here is not the implementation, it's the nature of allowing multiple people to work on the same item.

So, to summarise, there's nothing stopping you from having a business layer outside of the DB and keeping the increment atomic.  At the same time, you hopefully enjoy the benefits of having your business logic outside of the DB (which is a post in itself, but I'd argue that it's a large benefit).